# Android Studio build error - Program type already present

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, android-constraintlayout

I am getting the following error on building my app:

> Program type already present:
> android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior
> Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

The app is long standing, and I have just been making some changes. The change that caused this was to add an Activity (doesn't do anything yet). The Activity was added using the context menu new >> Activity >> basic activity. This added one with a ConstraintLayout in it, which I took out and replaced by a LinearLayout by editing the layout XML text. Virtually the same Activity and layout work fine in another app. (There is no ConstraintLayout in the whole project).

Now it won't build. Cleaned project, still won't build. Looked up similar problems but didn't really understand the answers (knowledge of Gradle very limited)!

Any advice appreciated.

As an aside, if anyone could point me to a simple tutorial on Gradle and how it works that would be great, I look at the build files and I have no idea what it is up to. Make files yes, Gradle no.

Comment: From answers on Stack Overflow, that error seems to be related to versioning. It may help if you can post your build.gradle file for the app.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it - for now. This is very old code imported from an Eclipse environment. The gradle script had an implementation line for a constraint view added - not by me, presumably because the wizard generated activity had one. I got rid of the constraint view anyway, so on removing the implementation line all was well again.

The problem I have is I really know nothing about gradle and the Android build process in general, so am terrified of touching anything in those scripts unless I really cannot avoid it.

I was much happier using Eclipse ....